# How to pass array between javascript and php mvc action

Tags: jquery

I am new in php and want to pass the array from javascript to php. On jquery side it should be like this:

```
var a= [];
a[0] = 'a';
a[1] = 'b';


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {myarray:a},
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg){
     $('.answer').html(msg);
   }
});
```

which type on the server should I select?

Comment: What exactly you mean by: `Which type on the server should I select?`?

Comment: So, you want to get the `a` array in PHP?  It's at `$_POST['myarray']`.

Answer (score 1):

In index.php you can get the data passed by the client side using `$_POST['myarray']`

```
$array = $_POST['myarray'];
```

`$array[0]` -> a

`$array[1]` -> b

Then do whatever you need to do and echo the response. This response will be your callback parameter `msg` in your $.ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Use array type.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to grab the POST values that are sent to php then this will echo out what the php is receiving from the request:

```
<?php
echo 'post values array items: ';
print_r($_POST);
```

$_POST is a super global which holds the POST data from the request that you are sending from your ajax request, more info on it can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php